# useState updates twice

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I have a component that gets a value from the local storage and does a `useQuery` to get some data:

```js
const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const [filterState, setFilter] = useState(false);

  const returnFilteredState = async () => {
    return await localforage.getItem<boolean>('watchedAndReviewedFilterd') || false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    returnFilteredState().then((value) => {
      setFilter(value);
    });
  }, []);

  const {error, loading, data: {moviesFromUser: movies} = {}} =
    useQuery(resolvers.queries.ReturnMoviesFromUser, {
      variables: {
        userId: currentUserVar().id,
        filter: filterState,
      },
    });
```

The problem is that the `ReturnMoviesFromUser` query is called twice. I think it's because of the `filterState` variable. If I set the `filter: true` the `ReturnMoviesFromUser` is only called once.

Comment: Initially `state === true` -> UseQuery fires. State is then set to true, UseQuery does not fire since nothing has changed. If initial state is false -> UseQuery fires. State is then set to true -> UseQuery fires again. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Yea thanks, I can just use the `await localforage.getItem<boolean>` directly on the `filter: `